# south migrate raises AttributeError for only one of my projects

Tags: python, django, django-south

On my development MacOS I have several django projects. When I run `python manage.py migrate` for all of them (except one) it works fine. But on only one project it returns this error:

```
Running migrations for main:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for main.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 233, in migrate_app
    migrator.load_initial_data(target, db=database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 224, in load_initial_data
    self.post_1_6(target, db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 242, in post_1_6
    old_cache = django.db.models.loading.cache
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loading'
```

The same project migrates good on production server. Do you have any ideas?

Here is `pip freeze` output:

```
Babel==1.3
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.6.5
Django-Select2==4.2.2
Fabric==1.8.2
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pillow==2.5.1
South==1.0
Unidecode==0.04.14
aldryn-blog==0.3.12
aldryn-common==0.0.3
argparse==1.2.1
args==0.1.0
bleach==1.4
cmsplugin-filer==0.9.5
cssselect==0.9.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-allauth==0.16.1
django-appconf==0.6
django-classy-tags==0.5.1
django-cms==3.0.2
django-compressor==1.3
django-cumulus==1.0.12
django-debug-toolbar==1.0.1
django-filer==0.9.5
django-grappelli==2.5.1
django-html-sanitizer==0.1.4
django-model-utils==2.0.1
django-mptt==0.6.0
django-polymorphic==0.5.3
django-reversion==1.8.0
django-sekizai==0.7
django-social-auth==0.7.28
django-suit==0.2.5
django-suit-ckeditor==0.0.2
django-suit-redactor==0.0.2
django-taggit==0.11.2
django-tinymce==1.5.2
django-widget-tweaks==1.3
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
djangocms-column==1.3
djangocms-file==0.0.1
djangocms-flash==0.0.2
djangocms-googlemap==0.0.5
djangocms-inherit==0.0.1
djangocms-installer==0.5.2
djangocms-link==1.3.4
djangocms-picture==0.0.2
djangocms-style==1.3
djangocms-teaser==0.0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.1.4
djangocms-video==0.0.1
easy-thumbnails==2.0.1
ecdsa==0.10
gunicorn==19.0.0
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
iso8601==0.1.10
keyring==3.6
lxml==3.3.1
mock==1.0.1
oauth2==1.5.211
oauthlib==0.6.1
os-diskconfig-python-novaclient-ext==0.1.2
os-networksv2-python-novaclient-ext==0.21
os-virtual-interfacesv2-python-novaclient-ext==0.15
paramiko==1.12.2
pbr==0.7.0
prettytable==0.7.2
progressbar==2.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pymongo==2.6.3
pymorphy==0.5.6
pyrax==1.6.3
python-memcached==1.53
python-novaclient==2.17.0
python-oauth2==0.5.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.1.22
python-swiftclient==2.0.3
pytils==0.3
pytz==2014.1
rackspace-auth-openstack==1.3
rackspace-novaclient==1.4
raven==4.0.4
rax-default-network-flags-python-novaclient-ext==0.2.3
rax-scheduled-images-python-novaclient-ext==0.2.1
requests==2.2.1
requests-oauthlib==0.4.0
retrying==1.2.1
simplejson==3.3.3
six==1.6.1
sqlparse==0.1.11
vboxapi==1.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
yandex-maps==0.7
```

---

I tried to reinstall django and upgraded south but result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you've done the following:

```
./manage.py schemamigration appname --initial
./manage.py migrate appname --fake
```

After changes have been made at a later time

```
./manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
./manage.py migrate appname
```

If the second block of code does not work, you might need to delete `south_migrationhistory`. First, delete the `migrations` folder in your app folder. Then (with SQL installed):

```
./manage.py dbshell
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table";
DROP TABLE south_migrationhistory;
.exit
```

Now do the routine I mentioned above (--initial, --fake).